# Cropped image isn't crisp swift

Tags: swift, imageview, crop

I am cropping my image view into a circle. When I do this the image isn't crisp. How can make make the image crisp while cropping the image?

```
    profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = (profilePicture.frame.size.width) / 2
    profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

[image]

Comment: you have to add some code to your question.

Comment: Ok I added the code I used

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sample Image]

I think your code is fine but I normally add clipToBounds = true and masksToBounds to false to get the result I want.  Also, make sure that the width and height of the profilePicture is the same and you set the contentMode to .Center

```
profilePicture.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)
profilePicture.contentMode = .Center
profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = (profilePicture.frame.size.width) / 2
profilePicture.layer.masksToBounds = false
profilePicture.clipToBounds = true
```

Comment: Hey Thank you for the response I appreciate it! So I tried what you suggested and the picture still is choppy around the edges, no change from before. Do you have any idea of why this is happening? Or do you have another way in mind I can do this task? Finally can you link me to an example of how your picture looks after doing it so I can see. Thank you

Comment: is that screenshot from a simulator or an iPhone? if it is from the Simulator, what version is it?

Comment: From the simulator, it is version 9.2

Comment: When I set my content mode to center, my image zooms way too far in. The only thing is that when this happens the circle doesn't look choppy anymore, and it actually looks crisp. So how would I zoom in a picture that I want to put in an imageview by a little bit to try and solve it that way?